# How to remove one item from dropdown with Vue jS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I want to make a button that remove one item from my dropdown but when I try using setup method when I click the item returns after 0.01s, soo that's my code:

```
<div class="inline-flex">
   <NumberInput/>
   <span 
      class="font-semibold text-gray-500 ml-3 mt-5 dark:text-gray-300" 
      v-html="'$'+itemsCart[4].price"
   ></span>
   <a 
      class="dark:text-gray-300" 
      @click="stayInDropdown = !stayInDropdown"
   >
      <svg 
         data-v-c52069be="" 
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
         width="14px" 
         height="14px" 
         viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
         fill="none" 
         stroke="currentColor" 
         stroke-width="2" 
         stroke-linecap="round" 
         stroke-linejoin="round" 
         class="cart-item-remove cursor-pointer feather feather-x"
      >
         <line 
            data-v-c52069be="" 
            x1="18" 
            y1="6" 
            x2="6" 
            y2="18"
         ></line>
         <line 
            data-v-c52069be="" 
            x1="6" 
            y1="6" 
            x2="18" 
            y2="18"
         ></line>
      </svg>
   </a>
</div>


<script>
   setup(){
      const stayInDropdown = ref(true)
      return{
         stayInDropdown,
      }
   }
</script>
```

[image]
This `x` will remove the item from dropdown.

Comment: Might try to use `preventDefault`?

Comment: what is that bro?